# Entity Framework saving data in one-to-one relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two tables as following:

Table 1:
ID(PK)
Name

Table 2:
ID(PK)
Email
Table1ID(FK)

I'm using Entity Framework to save data & once it is saved I retrieve it using Ajax call & display it in my view. However, the Foreign key column is not updated in the view while other data is. I have to manually refresh the web form to see updated foreign key value.

Here is some code from controller:

```
table2Obj = new Table2Object();
table2Obj.Email = emails;
table2Obj.Table1ID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlReferralTypes);
Context.Table2Objects.Add(table2Obj);
Context.SaveChanges();

List<Table2Object> table2Objs = Context.GetTable2Object();
string htmlView = RenderPartialViewToString("_ReferralList", table2Objs);
htmlView = HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(htmlView);
return Content("{\"MessageType\":\"success\",\"MessageContent\":\"Referral added successfully\",\"htmlPartialView\":\"" + htmlView + "\"}");
```

This is how view looks like:

```
    @model List<MyModels.Models.Table2Object>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    //display data
Email: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
Referral: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Table2.Name)
    }
```

Comment: After the SaveChanges() method call, you're using Context.GetTable2Oject() to get the updated data. What does the GetTable2Object() method look like?

Comment: it returns all records from Table 2 using simple Linq statement: return this.Table2Objects.ToList();

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [.Include()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx) method? I think in your case it would be:

```
this.Table2Objects.Include("Email").ToList();
```

Or

```
this.Table2Objects.Include(t => t.Email).ToList();
```

Hopefully that helps.